# Хороший FREE Weather API или доступный премиум

Tags: android, api, поиск-api, weather

Кто-нибудь может подсказать хороший, *желательно* фриварный и с минимальными ограничениями api, через который можно вытащить данные о погоде на ближайшие 5 дней. Желательно так же с вытаскиванием данных по геолокации.

Все нагугленные варианты пока не подходят.
Остановился на [worldweatheronline.com](http://worldweatheronline.com), но у него есть ограничение в количестве запросов и сайт временами падает.

Использование для некоммерческого **Android-приложения**.

Также подойдет доступный премиум.

Comment: @Barmaley тэг android тут не совсем уместен, ибо к программированию под дроид не относится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rp5](http://rp5.ru/docs/xml/ru?id=5483)

> Экспорт прогнозов погоды в Москве (ВВЦ) выполняется в формате XML с адреса http://rp5.ru/xml/5483/00000/ru. Если необходимо получить данные для другого населённого пункта, укажите значение его id. Это значение указано в конце адреса страницы с прогнозом погоды в интересующем населённом пункте. Например, указанное выше значение id=5483 можно было бы узнать на странице "Погода в Москве (ВВЦ)"